# Can I get headers in a WPF grid getting its rows from a data template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am implementing a headered table using grids above each other, so I can specify columns headers. There is one grid for headers, and one grid for every row in the table. It is not very practical, header widths has to be specified twice. Maybe I instead can have a ListView/DataGrid without all styling?

How can I get rid of this multi Grid approach?

Here is what I got:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
  <Grid Margin="0, 10, 0, 0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
            Text="header 1" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
            Text="header 2" />
  </Grid>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
          <Grid Margin="0, 10, 0, 0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
               Text="{Binding Property1}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
               Text="{Binding Property2}" />
          </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Grid.IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) attached property

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
  <Grid Margin="0, 10, 0, 0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="First" Width="40" />
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Second" Width="70" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
            Text="header 1" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
            Text="header 2" />
  </Grid>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
          <Grid Margin="0, 10, 0, 0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="First" />
              <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Second" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
               Text="{Binding Property1}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
               Text="{Binding Property2}" />
          </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Did not work, I tried SharedSizeGroup="a", SharedSizeGroup="b" etc, I only specified Width in the first set of ColumnDefinitions.

Comment: Maybe it is also a hack to use multiple grids.

Comment: @AndersLindén : my mistake : you have to put Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" as attribute of the StackPanel

Comment: I got it working, seems like I have to deal with multiple grids, thanks!

Comment: Setting Width to "*" was also a way to have widths dynamic, would be nice with some margins also...